# How do I view a report in WPF?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, report

How do I view a report in WPF without a third party app?
VB.NET, Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName I guess I am still deciding that too. I haven't displayed reports a desktop application yet and I don't know what report designer to use. I am looking for all sorts of answer in regards to displaying information in a report fashion.

Comment: How are you wanting to do so, in a print preview, or just on a form?

Comment: @MarkHall Either should work.

Comment: There are many different reporting engines and applications for WPF. If you gave us some requirements we could offer suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: My answer is a bit simplistic but without knowing the source of your data and the format you want to view it in, it is hard to be more specific.

I would start by looking into using a [FlowDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.aspx), see this [MSDN Magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163371.aspx) with some samples.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic reports without a 3rd party add-on, though if you are looking for rich features like PDF, excel export or just a good zoom or pagination engine you should use a third party solution.